# Does Octave have the xline function for drawing vertical lines?

Tags: octave

Does GNU Octave have the [xline function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xline.html) for drawing a vertical line with constant x values?

I searched around, but all results seem to be for matlab, not octave (as of Octave 5.2 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). Do I need to install an additional package for this?

Comment: This is a fairly recent addition to MATLAB, I’m sure either Octave hasn’t added it yet , or you need a very recent version of Octave. But you can just draw a line like we did before `xline` existed.

Comment: It does not appear that `xline` and `yline` have been added to Octave yet: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=58530

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but creating your own is "trivial".

```
xline = @(xval, varargin) line([xval xval], ylim, varargin{:});
```

This should work well for adding vertical lines in an existing figure (i.e. such that the `ylim` function will result in the size of the window automatically).

Comment: is there any way to make this function more compatible with the Matlab version? for example, I tried adding the `'--r'` to add a vertical dashed line, but it could draw it.

Comment: hi @Foad, this seems to be a limitation of the underlying `line` function. It does not take the same "specifier" syntax (e.g. `'r--'` ) as plot does (which I wasn't aware of either, tbh!). However, it _does_ take standard 'property/value' pairs, which will be passed to it appropriately from `xline` due to the `varargin` argument. So, e.g., you can achieve what you want as `xline( 10, 'linestyle', '--', 'color', 'r' )`.